# Analytical Expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to get an analytical expression for the following integral. But when I write this in mathematica, it just keeps on running and running. Do not give me any output. Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?

```
P\[Zeta]2[k_] = \[ScriptCapitalA]/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma])*
Exp[(-Log[k]^2 + Log[k0]^2)/(2*\[Sigma]^2)];
\[CapitalDelta]2[k_] = (4/9)^2 Integrate[(Exp[q]/
 k)^4 (Exp[-(Exp[q])^2/(
  2 k^2)])^2 (3 1/(Exp[q]/(
   Sqrt[3]*k))^3 (Sin[Exp[q]/(Sqrt[3]*k)] - 
    Exp[q]/(Sqrt[3]*k)*Cos[Exp[q]/(Sqrt[3]*k)]))^2*
P\[Zeta]2[Exp[q]], {q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

Here, `\[Sigma]`, `k_0` and `\[ScriptCapitalA]` are the constants.

Comment: Why do you think this can be integrated analytically? seems to be like a really hard one even for Mathematica.  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW21U.png) many integrals exist that do not have analytic antiderivative. Try numerical integration. Unless you happen to know this is supposed to be integrable.

Comment: With symbolic integration of something like this, not expecting an answer is par for the course; actually getting something should be considered a welcome surprise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am trying to solve it numerically, but I find the value of `\[CapitalDelta]2[k_]` zero. I have to explore the parameter space where it is not zero for the different values of `k_0` and `\[ScriptCapitalA]` for `\[sigma]=1` and I believe there exists a nonzero value of `\[CapitalDelta]2[k_]`. Can you please guide how I can do that?

Comment: What is known about the parameter range of `k,k0,\[ScriptCapitalA]`?

Comment: `k, k_0` ranges between `10^{-10 }` to `10^{-4}` and `\[ScriptCapitalA]` is `10^{-3}` to `1`

Comment: @adeelaafzal please [edit] your question to improve it. Please make your mind on what you need, articulate it in detail and make it consistent with the information you have shared in the comments.